# Changing the title bar on a Python window

Tags: python, user-interface, window, pyqt, titlebar

I'm looking to edit the title bar in a python window. I have compiled multiple different python widgets into one window using a main.py to get the ball rolling. I feel like I should add a piece of code in the main.py file rather than the widgets to change the title and icon in the title bar of the window.

Specifically, I want to edit the title and change the icon in a python generated window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`setWindowTitle(title)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) method on the main window.

Also, and unless the title changes dynamically in your app, it's probably better to change it in your interface file (if you made one, using `QtDesigner` for instance)

Comment: Excellent! In my special case, the correct code turned out to be     self.setWindowTitle("Hello World")

Comment: Which is logical because you're executing that code from your Main Window class :-) . By the way, you should probably read the PySide documentation if you ever need help (you'll need it with Qt, believe me) : http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/